# Magento 2.1.6 : How to override Adminhtml Module Sales view totals.phtml

Tags: magento-2.1

How to override `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml` file in magento2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">CompanyName_ExtensionName::totals.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

And i copied `totals.phtml` file to `app\code\CompanyName\ExtensionName\view\adminhtml\templates\` folder.

I tried to clean cache and upgrade nothing happen So please anyone have any idea what is wrong? or any another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to follow the below steps:

**app\code\CompanyName\ExtensionName\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">CompanyName_ExtensionName::order/totals.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Copy original file into following location:

**CompanyName/ExtensionName/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml**

Clear cache.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine!.  Thank you Manashvi birla.

Comment: I am not able to call my custom class after override the totals.phtml

Answer (score 2):

Try following way:

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/totals.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```