# How can I override module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\comments\view.phtml?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I did similar at [Magento 2.1.6 : How to override Adminhtml Module Sales view totals.phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175617/magento-2-1-6-how-to-override-adminhtml-module-sales-view-totals-phtml) but nothing change? There are 2 xml use the same template sales_order_invoice_addcomment & sales_order_creditmemo_addcomment (Magento 2.3)

Comment: From where do you want to override it, in `sales_order_invoice_view` or `shipment` or ... ?

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to rewrite `order/comments/view.phtml` from `adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml`

You can see : `vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml`

1. > app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceBlock name="order_comments">
               <action method="setTemplate">
                   <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::order/comments/view.phtml</argument>
               </action>
           </referenceBlock>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
2. > app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/templates/order/comments/view.phtml

   ```
   Your content here...
   ```
3. > php bin/magento c:f

Comment: Hello @prince can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300095/magento-2-how-to-import-custom-linkproducts